# How to get authorize code to dismiss login page with oauth2 wso2 identity server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity with structure below:
Client -> My Web Application (/my-app) -> WSO2-is (this is private zone)
I created service provider on WSO2-is and config all of the necessary information (use OAuth2).
Client access `/my-app/login?client-id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code...`
Then will be submit username + password. My application catch the submit request, then send the request to [WSO2-is endpoint](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/endpoint/authz/OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java): https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize.
How to init request with parameters to get authorization code directly?
I was referenced wso2-is documentation. The authorization code will be insert into a table [`IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE`](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/dao/SQLQueries.java). With the authorization code, i gonna get access token from https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token endpoint. 
I can get access token directly with oauth2/token endpoint by grant_type is password, but I'm only want to get access token by workflow description above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator` from the Local Authenticator section to skip the login page as below.
You also might want to skip the login consent as well.

[image]

[Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Basic+Auth+Request+Path+Authentication)

Cheers