# WSO2 Api Manager - bypass sign in page when invoking API (oauth2 authorization grant code)

Tags: api, authentication, wso2

I'm facing the same issue as the one posted at ([How to get authorize code to dismiss login page with oauth2 wso2 identity server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002175/how-to-get-authorize-code-to-dismiss-login-page-with-oauth2-wso2-identity-server))

I tried to follow the solution instructions, but in my case, the drop-down menu under "Request Path Authentication Configuration" is empty; no options listed.

[image]

I checked the application-authentication.xml file under /opt/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/conf/identity and I have this:

[image]

[image]

I'll apprecitate any support you can provide. Thanks. Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this thread, and as I was not able to get a solution, I solved it by running an instnace of the WSO2 Identity Server and handle the security through this product, instead of using the IS features the API manager has embedded. cheers!